# Deploying a Windows Web App?

Tags: sql-server, iis

A nonprofit I donate sometime to was given a 'web app' by another institution to track information.  I'm not a Microsoft guy so I'm at a bit of a loss here and and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to get this thing online.

I have an .MDF and .LDF file which I understand to be a SQL Server Database file and transaction log.  The other folder has 197 items in it of the following file types:

- .xls
- .sql
- .xlsx
- .rpt
- .frm
- .frx
- .doc
- .db
- .bas
- .vbp
- .vbw
- .ppt
- .gif
- .jpg

The obvious extensions in there I recognize (.xls, .sql, .xlsx, .doc, etc), but the others I have no idea on.

Based on this information does it even look like I have all the required files and if so any help getting me started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.frm, .frx, .bas, and especially .vbp indicate that these are really old-school vb6-era (circa 1999) forms. You'd need visual basic/visual studio 6 to build the project. I'd run. Run far, and run fast.

Especially the .frm/.frx pair. To see this in a web app, they're either just plain lying that this is a web app, and not a vb6 forms app, or (almost worse) are embedding vb6 forms in a page as activeX controls, which would limit you to Internet Explorer only, and even then recent versions require you to jump through extra hoops before they will let you do this. The best you can hope for is the vb6 forms are just an installer app.

Look for a readme file that has install instructions.

Comment: Thanks @Joel Coehoorn - That gets me started down some path... even if it's scary :)  Unfortunately there is no readme anywhere in the set of files that was given to me.  I'll see if I can track that down though.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It doesn't look like you have all the files necessary unless your site is suppose to just offer people a internet medium to download or view the above documents and presentation.